# Symfony2 MopaBootstrapBundle There is no "less" filter error

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, less

I get ("There is no "less" filter.") error on my pages, but I can't seem to resolve it. I have less installed on my mac. How do I tell symfony to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the Node modules path by running:

```
find / -name node_modules -type d
```

Then set to the `node_paths` option:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            node_paths: /usr/lib/node_modules
            compress:   true
            apply_to:   "\.less$"
```

Comment: what is the node_modules? I don't have that

Comment: Do you have the LESS module installed for Node.js or not?

Comment: Ok, I had less installed but not nodejs, I figured it out with your answer. thx

Answer (score 0):

You must install node (apt-get install node), create link (ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node) and everything should be ok.